# N1qlPrimaryIndexed replacement

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

After update the project to Spring Data Couchbase 4, the annotation `N1qlPrimaryIndexed` appears as deprecated,

```
@Repository
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
public interface HostelRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<Hostel, String> {
}
```

I would like to know if there is a replacement for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should not be using @N1qlPrimaryIndexed in production, as it creates under-optimized indexes. As long as you have at least one index per document type, you should fine without it.

On Spring Dara Couchabse 4, we have a new set of annotations for indexing.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.repository.indexing